# Easiest way to send basic data from Android to ESP8266 through WiFi

Tags: esp8266, wifi, android

I'm not really familiar with network protocols, but my application is very simple:

1. The ESP8266 is connected to the phone's WiFi hotspot (so they're both on the same network).
2. The phone sends 1 (as in 0x1) to the ESP8266 periodically (at ~4 Hz).
3. When the ESP8266 receives 1, it turns on an LED for a small period of time.

Would a simple HTTP request work well enough? Or are there other methods more suited for my application?